# How to get current audio/video file name running or not in windows media player Using python

Tags: python, wmp

I have tried this code able to get only playlist information but I am looking for current Audio file name is running or not

```
import win32com.client 

w=win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('WMPlayer.OCX',0) 
pl=w.playlistCollection.getByName('All Music')[0] 
s=pl[1] 
print s.name, s.duration
w.currentMedia=s
w.IsPlaying=0
print "w.currentMedia",w.currentMedia
```